# Is a homogeneous Banach space on $\mathbb T$ always well defined?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

A **homogeneous Banach space** $B$ on group $\mathbb T=\mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z$ is a linear subspace $B$ of $L^1(\mathbb T)$ having a norm $\|\ \|_B\ge\|\ \|_{L^1}$ under which it is a Banach space, and having the following properties:

1. If $f\in B$ and $\tau\in\mathbb T$, then $f_\tau\in B$ and $\|f_\tau\|_B=\|f\|_B$ (where $f_\tau=f(t-\tau)$).
2. For all $f\in B\quad $, $\tau, \tau_0\in\mathbb T,\quad $$\lim_{\tau\to\tau_0}\|f_\tau-f_{\tau_0}\|=0.$

I am wondering whether this is well-defined. For instance, if we have $f_1,f_2\in B\subseteq L^1(\mathbb T)$ and $f_1=f_2$ in $L^1(\mathbb T)$, then the values of $f_1$ and $f_2$ differ at most at a zero measure set. But it is also possible that $f_1\ne f_2$ in $B$ and in which case, it does not make sense to say the $B$-norm of $f_1$ or $f_2$ since they are considered to be one element in $L^1(\mathbb T)$ and also in the subspace $B$ of $L^1(\mathbb T)$. Whereas, $\|f_1\|_B\ne\|f_2\|_B$ is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's be extremely explicit about all the objects involved. We have the vector space $\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{T})$ of all measurable functions $f \colon \mathbb{T} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{T}} |f| \, dt < \infty$ and on this space we have a map $\| \cdot \|_{L^1} \colon \mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{T}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$ \| f \|_{L^1} = \int_{\mathbb{T}} |f| \, dt. $$
The map $\| \cdot \|_{L^1}$ is not a norm on $\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{T})$, only a semi-norm so we quotient out and replace $\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{T})$ with the space $L^1(\mathbb{T})$ of equivalence classes (equal a.e). Elements in $L^1(\mathbb{T})$ should be denoted by $[f]$ (but they aren't) and the $L^1$ norm descends to $L^1(\mathbb{T})$ and defines an actual norm
$$ \| [f] \|_{L^1} = \| f \|_{L^1}. $$

Now, a homogeneous Banach subspace $B$ is a subspace of $L^1(\mathbb{T})$, not of $\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{T})$ so the elements of $B$ are themselves equivalence classes. Going to your scenario, when you write $f_1,f_2 \in B \subseteq L^1(\mathbb{T})$, the only way to interpret it with what I wrote above is that $[f_1],[f_2] \in B \subseteq L^1(\mathbb{T})$. Then indeed it is possible that $f_1,f_2$ differ on a zero measure set but it is not possible that "$f_1 \neq f_2$ in $B$" because $B$ itself is a subspace of equivalence classes and this doesn't even make any sense.

The point is that there is some abuse of notation going on with all of this. When people say that $B = C(\mathbb{T})$ with the $\| \cdot \|_{\infty}$ norm is a homogeneous Banach space on $\mathbb{T}$, they actually mean the space 
$$ B = \{ [f] \, | \, f \in C(\mathbb{T}) \} $$
of equivalence classes (so that it becomes a subspace of $L^1(\mathbb{T})$). In each equivalence class $[f]$ one has the continuous function $f$ but also other functions $g \in [f]$ which are not necessarily continuous but equal to $f$ a.e. However, if $f \in C(\mathbb{T})$ then in each equivalence class $[f]$, there is only **one** continuous function which is $f$ itself. Hence, one can identify $[f]$ with $f$ and define $\| [f] \|_{\infty} = \| f \|_{\infty}$.

Now, it is possible that $[f_1] = [f_2] \in B \subseteq L^1(\mathbb{T})$ and that $f_1$ is continuous and $f_2$ is not but $f_1 = f_2$ a.e. Note that this doesn't mean that $f_1 \neq f_2$ in $C(\mathbb{T})$ as $f_2$ doesn't even belong there. However, if $[f_1] = [f_2] \in B \subseteq L^1(\mathbb{T})$ and both $f_1,f_2$ are continuous then $f_1 = f_2$ (not only a.e) and so $f_1,f_2$ are indeed the same function in $C(\mathbb{T})$.

Comment: The same goes with your objection about "not using the Lebesgue measure on ". You might imagine putting a different measure  on $\mathbb{T}$ and considering $\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{T},\mu)$ functions with respect to $\mu$. But to make it a homogeneous subspace of $L^1(\mathbb{T},dt)$, you need to talk about equivalence classes a.e (with respect to the Lebesgue measure  because you need a subspace of $L^1(\mathbb{T},dt)$). Then you need to show that the norm $\| \cdot \|_{L^1(\mu)}$ is well-defined on those equivalence classes.

Comment: Crystal clear! Reply to your comment: Do you mean to show $\|\cdot\|_B$ is well-defined on the equivalence classes?

Comment: @Bach: Yes. For example, when you take $B = C^0(\mathbb{T})$, you are actually taking equivalence classes and then you need to show that in each equivalence class $[f]$ you have exactly one continuous representative which you then use to define the norm of the equivalence class (the sup norm). When $B = L^p(\mathbb{T})$, you can use any representative because the integral will be defined and won't depend on the representative. And so on. This is all very "tiresome" and "obvious" so most treatments just sweep it under the rug.

Answer (score 1):

I rephrase myself.

Suppose $A$ is a veckor space and that $B$ is a subspace, then any two vectors  of $B$ are equal if and only if they are equal in $A$.

Comment: But I supposed $f_1=f_2$ in $L^1(\mathbb T)$. How do you know that $f_1$ and $f_2$ differ in $B$ implies that they must differ on a larger set than one of measure zero? We do not know much about $B$ except the two properties. For instance, the measure may not even be the Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb R$ in $B$.